# how to get given JSON value?

Tags: json, android-json

i am trying to get this given Jso value, but "data" value not get.

```
{
"result": {
"success": true,
"data": {
  "eid": "mcXRukleFJkd2O2xZvE$5w",
  "points_earned": 0,
  "post_sharing_params": {
    "message": "ajgdakalhajgajabakjkaaahkakakaha. \r\n#LifeAtCapgemini  "
  }
}
}
}
```

- I create one function to access this value, but "data" Json object value is not assign my model object, so please tell me proper solution.

  ```
  try {
      JSONObject resultJsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
      if (resultJsonObject.length() != 0 && resultJsonObject != null) {
          try {
              mFeedActionCustomModel.setFeed_success(BaseParser.optString(resultJsonObject, "success"));
              try {
                  JSONObject dataJsonObject = resultJsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
                  if (dataJsonObject.length() != 0 && dataJsonObject != null) {
                      mFeedActionCustomModel.setEid(BaseParser.optString(dataJsonObject, "eid"));
                      mFeedActionCustomModel.setPointsEarned(BaseParser.optString(dataJsonObject, "points_earned"));
                      try {
                          JSONObject postSharingParamsJsonObject = dataJsonObject.optJSONObject("post_sharing_params");
                          if (postSharingParamsJsonObject.length() != 0 && postSharingParamsJsonObject != null) {
                              mFeedActionCustomModel.setFeed_message(BaseParser.optString(postSharingParamsJsonObject, "message"));
                          }
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                      }
                  }
              } catch (Exception e) {
              }
          } catch (Exception e) {
          }
      }
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
  ```

Comment: I suggest logging your `Exception`(s) instead of ignoring them completely. That way, you can have an holistic view of the root cause of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply:

```
JSONObject dataJsonObject = resultJsonObject.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("data");
```

You haven't browsed the `result` attribute yet (where `data` is the child of).

Comment: @HiteshTarbundiya glad to be of help. Please don't forget to upvote this answer if it has helped you.

Comment: my reputation is low , i am not able to upvoted, but this one is correct and working for me, thanks again.

Comment: Not upvote. Tick on the check mark underneath the score value arrows.

Comment: I have one more problem in Json can you explain this one, how to access, if possible for you..

Comment: I do not understand your question. Please elaborate clearly.